# Data from table won't show up if <script> is in the string. Stops execution

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

So I inputted data into my table using a form, and used

```
$username =    mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
```

the mysqli_real_escape_string to work around SQL injections. Using this method will result the data to be saved like this, in the case of someone trying to use a script as an input `<script> some bad script </script>`
and surely the injection won't happen, but I noticed that while trying to retrieve data from the table, the execution will stop once it reaches the username that is saved like that. I tried editing the table and removing the `<script> </script>` parts and refreshed the page, and as expected the execution didn't stop and finished properly. I used the following code to retrieve the data from the table

```
require_once ('dbconnect.php');

$title= "The App";


$qry =  "SELECT * FROM businesses ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
$info = array();

while($row_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  { $info= $row_info;
echo " The ID:" . $row_info['buss_id'] . "<br>" . "The username:" . $row_info['username'] . "<br>";
  }
```

Note: dbconnect.php has the $con variable. Thank you.
I would also like to ask about the part in the code where it says

```
$info=$row_info;
```

I was following a tutorial and they did it that way, however clearly I could have the same result by using the $row_info variable. Any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `the mysqli_real_escape_string to work around SQL injections` :- No it's not. You have to use `prepared statements` for that

Comment: @ Anant - Thanks so much for the heads up, I will look it up!

Comment: When displaying strings in an HTML document that should not contain markup themselves, use `htmlspecialchars($row_info['username'])`. See http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you're talking about removing javascripts from form input (e.g. attempt to save malicious javascript to your forum / message board so you will display them to all other visitors).

Both [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) only work against [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), (i.e. attempt to trick your program to run SQL statement that is not supposed to run). Of cause you should use them in your form input. But they are security on a different abstraction level than your question concerned.

You'd need to do [HTML sanitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) to your text input before saving to your database, or before displaying them to anyone. You should

1. use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on the string; or
2. use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with appropriate [Sanitize Filter](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php); or
3. If you do not wish to have HTML for your user input, you may use [htmlspecialchar](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to convert them into HTML-save plain text.

Comment: You're the real MVP. Do you think using a sanitize function like this one will do?
function sanitize($data)
{
 return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($data)));
}

Comment: Not sure where you'd use this `sanitize()` function. SQL escaping only make sense before insert. So using it against data selected from DB (as shown in your code) doesn't help. Also if you do `htmlentities()`, probably no need to use `strip_tags()` at all.

Comment: Also, `mysqli_*` functions are the old database usage style that will probably be depreciated in the future (like [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)). You'd better off learn and use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for database queries. [This tutorials](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) might help.

Comment: Yeah I meant to use the sanitize function for insert statements. like sanitize($username) to strip the username from any suspicious tags, then insert it into the database. And yes I'll work on the PDO style. Thanks a lot for your help, instead of just down voting a clearly beginner's question.

Comment: In that case, I think `function sanitize($data) { return mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($data)); }` could do the trick. However, the usual practice I saw is to escape the SQL values before insert, while sanitize the data right before displaying.

Comment: If you're talking about username, wouldn't it be best to make sure it is alphanumeric before accepting it? i.e. use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check that there's only alphabet and numbers in it.

Comment: Yes using preg_match() would be the best practice for usernames. Good point. Regarding sanitizing the data before inserting them to the database, I think it'll be better than just escaping it, cause the user can input something like that script tags shown in the question, which would mess up the data retrieval process. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Storing malicious javascript in database is not the problem. Showing them is. I'd usually do `strip_tag` or `htmlspecialchars` before echo the text to viewers. e.g. `echo "The username:" . strip_tag($row_info['username']); `.

Comment: Man you've helped me a ton! that's a day's worth of research time right there. I wish I could repay you somehow. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Before insert to database

```
$text =  addslashes(htmlspecialchars($text));
```

Output

```
$text = stripslashes(trim(implode('',explode('\\',$text))));

echo $text;
```

This should works fine

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful =)